# Next.JS Server Component Infinite Loop

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using a Server Component in Next.JS for the first time to grab some data from Firestore and use it in a client component. However, I have hit a mystery infinite loop, where this error is being thrown to the server:
`- error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at String.replace (<anonymous>)`

Here are the components in question:

```js
'use client'
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "@/lib/context";
import { getBenchmarksByUser } from "./BenchmarkMenu";

export default function BenchmarkBrowser() {
    
    // Ask Context for user so we have UID
    const { user } = useContext(UserContext);

    // Watch the state of our Benchmarks
    const [benchmarks, setBenchmarks] = useState([]);

    // Send the server a request for our Benchmarks
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("BenchmarkBrowser component is rendered.");
        getBenchmarksByUser(user.uid).then((res) => {
            console.log("benchmarks received by client", res);
            setBenchmarks(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error!", err);
        });
    }, [user.uid]);

    return (
        <>
        <h1>benchmark browser...</h1>
        </>
    );
}
```

And the server component

```js
'use server'
import { db } from "@/lib/firebase";
import { query, getDocs, collection, orderBy, limit } from "firebase/firestore";

export async function getBenchmarksByUser(uid) {

    console.log("server uid", uid);
    const benchmarksQuery = query(collection(db, 'users/' + uid + '/benchmarks'), orderBy('created'), limit(5));
    const benchmarkDocs = await getDocs(benchmarksQuery);
    
    console.log("benchmarks", benchmarkDocs.docs.length);
    return benchmarkDocs;

}


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Avoid using an object created during rendering as a dependency. Instead, create the object inside the Effect as the docs say here: https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#removing-unnecessary-object-dependencies

Comment: I can't call the useContext hook inside of useEffect so that doesn't work for me. I guess I need to find a different way to get the user's uid

Comment: Yes, maybe. I have no experience with `useContext()` so far, so unfortunately I can't say more about it.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the nudge in the right direction. I'm thinking calling useContext on every page where I need the {user} is not the best way to handle it